# Specify artboard PDF page order in Affinity Designer export?

Tags: export, affinity-designer

I'm exporting a PDF of four artboards in AD but they are coming out backwards, and I have to split and merge the PDF to get what I'm looking for. Is there a method to specify the page order upon export? I can't see it anywhere, and the help files don't help in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exported page order is defined by the order of the artboards in the layers palette. The artboard at the bottom is page 1, the next one up is page 2, etc.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Slightly conceptually odd that the lowermost layer should be the first in the export, but whatever, it works!

Comment: It is a little odd, but the artboards feature is relatively new to AD so I suspect that it will improve with time. I'll take a small amount of oddness if it keeps me from subscribing to Creative Cloud! ;-)